# Laravel Livewire 404 wire:click.prevent after join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I have a laravel project with livewire, in blade i have various wire:click.prevent that funcion is in row.php, but is returning 404 error
This error ocurs after I modified model query adding joins, does it have something to do with it?

Row.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Tolls\Payments;

use App\Jobs\SingleConsultPtvJob;
use App\Jobs\SingleSyncPtvJob;
use App\Jobs\SingleVerifyPaymentJob;
use App\Models\TollPayment;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Row extends Component
{
    public $payment;
    public $maxDiferencePtv;
    public $deleted = false;
    public $total_duplicates = 0;
    public $tollPaymentAction;

    protected function getListeners()
    {
        return [
            'evnt_set_as_verified_'.$this->payment->id => 'setAsVerified',
            'setPtvRouteCostAsChecked' => 'setPtvRouteCostAsChecked'
        ];
    }

    public function mount($payment, $maxDiferencePtv)
    {
        $this->maxDiferencePtv = $maxDiferencePtv;
        $this->payment = $payment;
        $this->total_duplicates = $payment->duplicates_count;
    }

    public function setAsVerified($turn)
    {
        $fields = [];
        if ($turn == 1) {
            $fields['entry_verification_status'] = 1;
        } else {
            $fields['departure_verification_status'] = 1;
        }
        $payment = $this->payment;
        $payment->update($fields);

        $this->payment = TollPayment::withCount('duplicates')->find($this->payment->id);
    }

    public function setPtvRouteCostAsChecked($paymentId) {
        if ($paymentId === $this->payment->id) {
            $this->payment->where('id', $paymentId)->update(['ptv_route_cost_checked' => 1]);
            $this->payment = TollPayment::withCount('duplicates')->find($paymentId);
        }
    }

    public function setStatus($turn)
    {
        $fields = [];
        if ($turn == 1) {
            $fields['entry_verification_status'] = 2;
        } else {
            $fields['departure_verification_status'] = 2;
        }
        $payment = $this->payment;
        $payment->update($fields);
        $this->payment = TollPayment::withCount('duplicates')->find($this->payment->id);
    }

    public function showDuplicates()
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('show_duplicates', ['rows' => $this->payment->duplicates]);
    }

    public function showDetailsCosts()
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('show_details_costs', [
            'payment' => [
                'id'                        => $this->payment->id,
                'society'                   => $this->payment->society,
                'entry_date'                => $this->payment->entry_date,
                'entry_hour'                => $this->payment->entry_hour,
                'departure_date'            => $this->payment->departure_date,
                'departure_hour'            => $this->payment->departure_hour,
                'amount_without_vat'        => $this->payment->amount_without_vat,
                'vat'                       => $this->payment->vat,
                'amount_with_vat'           => $this->payment->amount_with_vat,
                'ptv_route_cost'            => $this->payment->ptv_route_cost,
                'ptv_route_cost_retries'    => $this->payment->ptv_route_cost_retries,
                'ptv_route_cost_difference' => $this->payment->ptv_route_cost_difference,
                'ptv_route_cost_checked'    => $this->payment->ptv_route_cost_checked,
                'max_difference_ptv_cost'   => $this->maxDiferencePtv,
                'ptv_entry_cords'           => $this->payment->ptv_entry_cords,
                'ptv_departure_cords'       => $this->payment->ptv_departure_cords
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function showMapFn($turn)
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('show_map', [
            'paymentId'  => $this->payment->id,
            'turn'       => $turn,
            'evnt'       => 'evnt_set_as_verified_'.$this->payment->id,
            'verify_log' => $this->payment->verify_log,
        ]);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.backend.tolls.payments.row');
    }
    
    public function tollPaymentAction($tollPaymentAction, $paymentId) {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

        try {
            switch ($tollPaymentAction) {
                case 1:
                    dispatch(new SingleVerifyPaymentJob($paymentId));
                    break;
                
                case 2:
                    dispatch(new SingleSyncPtvJob($paymentId));
                    break;
                
                case 3:
                    request()->session()->forget('ptvCostRetries');
                    dispatch(new SingleConsultPtvJob($paymentId));

            }
           
            if ($tollPaymentAction == 3 ) {
                $ptvCostRetries = request()->session()->get('ptvCostRetries');
                $tollPaymentPrice = request()->session()->get('tollPaymentPrice');
                if ($ptvCostRetries != null) {
                    $displayText = "<p>Importe: " . $tollPaymentPrice . "€ </p>";
                    $displayText .= "<table>";
                    $displayText .= "<thead><tr><th width='75%'>Petición PTV</th><th width='25%'>Importe PTV</th></tr></thead>";
                
                    foreach ($ptvCostRetries as $key => $value) {
                        if (isset($value["isFinalResult"])) {
                            $displayText .= "<tr><td style='color:#24b314' width='75%'>". $value['info'] . "</td><td style='color:#24b314' width='25%'>". $value['price'] ."€</td></tr>";

                        }else {
                            $displayText .= "<tr><td width='75%'>". $value['info'] . "</td><td width='25%'>". $value['price'] ."€</td></tr>";

                        }
                    }
    
                    $displayText .= "</table>";
                    
                    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('info-debug', [
                        'message' => $displayText,
                        'redirect' => null,
                    ]);

                }else {
                    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', [
                        'type' => 'error',
                        'message' => "No se ha podido processar la solicitud",
                        'redirect' => null,
                    ]);
                }

            }else {
                $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', [
                    'type' => 'success',
                    'message' => 'La solicitud se ha procesado correctamente.',
                    'redirect' => null,
                ]);

            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e);
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', [
                'type' => 'error',
                'message' => 'La solicitud no se ha procesado correctamente.',
                'redirect' => null,
            ]);
        }
    }
    
}
```

row.blade.php

```
<a href="#" wire:click.prevent="showMapFn(2)" id="payment_btn_2_{{ $payment->id }}">
```

Index.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Tolls\Payments;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Device;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\TollInvoice;
use App\Models\TollPayment;
use App\Models\TollContract;
use App\Models\TransicsVehicle;
use App\Traits\Livewire\Filters;
use App\Exports\ExportTollPayments;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Exports\ExportTollPaymentsQueued;
use App\Jobs\NotifyUserOfCompletedExport;
use App\Models\VehicleType;

class Index extends Component
{
    use Filters;

    public $fileName = "";

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->useCachedRows();
    }

    public function getRowsQueryProperty()
    {
        $query = TollPayment::
        join('transics_vehicles', 'transics_vehicles.id', '=', 'toll_payments.device_id')
        ->join('tolls as in', 'in.id', '=', 'toll_payments.entry_toll_id')
        ->join('tolls as out', 'out.id', '=', 'toll_payments.departure_toll_id')
        ->with('in', 'out')        
        ->orderBy('entry_date', 'ASC')->orderBy('entry_hour', 'ASC')
        ->filter($this->filters);

        return $query;
    }

    public function getContractsProperty()
    {
        return TollContract::all();
    }


    public function getDevicesProperty()
    {
        return TransicsVehicle::all();
    }

    public function getInvoicesProperty()
    {
        return TollInvoice::all();
    }

    public function exportExcel()
    {
        $from = Carbon::parse($this->filters['from']);
        $to = Carbon::parse($this->filters['to']);
        $diff = $to->diffInDays($from);
        $this->fileName = 'Export_'.rand().'.xlsx';
        if ($diff > 15) {
            (new ExportTollPaymentsQueued($this->filters))->store('public/excels/'.$this->fileName)->chain([
                new NotifyUserOfCompletedExport(request()->user(), $this->fileName, $this->filters),
            ]);

            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', [
                'type' => 'success',
                'message' => trans('Estamos preparando el archivo excel, te avisaremos por email ...'),
                'redirect' => null,
            ]);
        } else {
            ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
            ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
            return Excel::download(new ExportTollPayments($this->filters), 'Cobros.xlsx');
        }
    }
    public function render()
    {
        $vehiclesTypes = VehicleType::all()->pluck('profile_name','id')->toArray();

        return view('livewire.backend.tolls.payments.index', [
            'payments' => $this->filter ? $this->rows : [],
            'vehicles_type_data' => $vehiclesTypes,
            'max_diference_ptv' => getSetting('max_difference_ptv_cost'),
        ]);
    }

}
```

does it have something to do with joins or i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the join overrides the payment id and that field is required to prevent and laravel returns 404 instead of returning model not found :/

I solved doing this

```
$query = TollPayment::select('toll_payments.*')
    ->leftjoin('transics_vehicles', 'transics_vehicles.id', '=', 'toll_payments.device_id')
    ->leftjoin('tolls as in', 'in.id', '=', 'toll_payments.entry_toll_id')
    ->leftjoin('tolls as out', 'out.id', '=', 'toll_payments.departure_toll_id')
    ->with('in', 'out')        
    ->orderBy('entry_date', 'ASC')->orderBy('entry_hour', 'ASC')
    ->filter($this->filters);
```

instead of this

```
$query = TollPayment::
    join('transics_vehicles', 'transics_vehicles.id', '=', 'toll_payments.device_id')
    ->join('tolls as in', 'in.id', '=', 'toll_payments.entry_toll_id')
    ->join('tolls as out', 'out.id', '=', 'toll_payments.departure_toll_id')
    ->with('in', 'out')        
    ->orderBy('entry_date', 'ASC')->orderBy('entry_hour', 'ASC')
    ->filter($this->filters);
```